# How should I expose a collection on a UserControl?

Tags: silverlight, data-binding, silverlight-4.0, binding, observablecollection

I'm creating a UserControl which will be used in various scenarios.  I need to expose a collection of strings from the UserControl and I'm not sure how to do it.

The two possible uses I see are:

- a control on its containing control binds to the collection, e.g. a ListBox;
- a property on the containing control's ViewModel needs to bind to the collection.

I can get the former to work with a public ObservableCollection<String> property on the UserControl but it won't work for the latter.  (I get "Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.String]'.")

Is there a solution that will work for both?

**EDIT**

This is my stab at a UML diagram showing what I'm doing:

[image: a uml diagram]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is just that the binder can't understand generics. You should be able to get around that by inheriting from `ObservableCollection<string>` to make a non-generic class. You can use something like this:

```
class StringCollection : ObservableCollection<string> { }
```

Since you are using that property as a target of a binding, you must declare it as a DependencyProperty:

```
class ObjectSelectorView
{
    public StringCollection ObjectNames
    {
        get { return (StringCollection)GetValue(ObjectNamesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ObjectNamesProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ObjectNames.
    // This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObjectNamesProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("ObjectNames", typeof(StringCollection),
            typeof(ObjectSelectorView), null);
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've tried that but I got the same error.  But the first question is: is an ObservableCollection (or derivative) the right way to go?

Comment: @SGarratt: You need to declare the property as a `DependencyProperty` (see my edit). You use an `ObservableCollection` when you need to modify the collection after it's been bound to a control. Since you're using data binding, presumably you want the collection to be observable.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I've implemented it as a DependencyProperty and the error has gone but the data is still not available in the MainViewModel - the collection there remains empty, no matter how many strings start are added in the ObjectSelectorViewModel.

Comment: @SGarratt: I don't know how all of your objects correlate, but you need to make sure that the `StringCollection` instance in your `MainView` is the same instance that's used in all your other objects. It sounds like that's not happening, but it's impossible to tell without seeing your code.

Comment: The problem is solved.  I've marked yours as the answer because  your comments led me to it.  It's important to note that **it wasn't necessary to implement the StringCollection**: ObservableCollection<String> works well.  But I did implement it as a DependencyProperty and something wasn't hooking up properly along the way so thanks for making me break it down and look at it all again.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that the error you are seeing is actually the result of your not implementing this property as dependency property.  You should be using a dependency property here.

Don't expose the property on your control as a concrete ObservableCollection of anything.  Instead expose the property as a simple non-generic `IList`.

In your control's constructor assign an initial empty instance of `ObservableCollection<String>` to this property.  However the property should have a public setter and therefore your initial collection instance may be replaced by some other implementer of `IList`.  Therefore you should limit your usage of this property internally to `IList` or gracefully degrade behaviour if the current instance does not have the other interfaces you might want.

Comment: How odd: I've written this comment once already, but it's not here.  I've followed your advice, both in terms of implementing as a dependency property (in the ObjectSelectorView, which is where I assumed you meant it) and as an IList.  The error has gone but the data is not available from the MainViewModel.  I can still bind another element to it in the MainView XAML (using ElementName syntax) but binding it to a collection in the MainViewModel doesn't work.  The collection is empty.